# Assignment in C++ changes the numbers

Tags: c++, c++17

I am writing quicksort and I get segfault. I tried the find the    source of error and it seems in partition function when I assign `i` I get `15460` and for `j` I get `-1`. I could not figure out how that can happen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int partition(std::vector<int>& A, int lo, int hi) {
    int i = lo;
    int j = hi + 1;
    while (true) {
        while (A[++i] < A[lo])
            if (i == hi) break;
        while (A[lo] < A[--j])
            if (j == lo) break;
        if (i >= j) std::swap(A[i], A[j]);
    }
    std::swap(A[lo], A[j]);
    return j;
}

void sort(std::vector<int>& A, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) return;
    int j = partition(A, lo, hi);
    sort(A, lo, j - 1);
    sort(A, j + 1, hi);
}

void sort(std::vector<int>& A) {
    std::random_device random_device;
    std::mt19937 rng(random_device());
    std::shuffle(std::begin(A), std::end(A), rng);
    sort(A, 0, A.size() - 1);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> V = {2, 1};
    sort(V);
    for (const auto& item: V) std::cout << item;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you are saying *I assign i I get 15460 and for j I get -1*?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: *I could not figure out how that can happen.* --  Advice -- Replace `[ ]` with calls to `at()` to check for anywhere you may be going out-of-bounds of your vector, for example `while (A.at(++i) < A.at(lo))`.  If you are going out-of-bounds, a `std::out_of_range` exception will be thrown.

Comment: Your `while (true)` loop in `partition` never exits, and only stops when it segfaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function partition() you have nested while loops. The outer one never quits, as mentioned by 1201ProgramAlarm.
The two inner loops keep in-/decrementing i/j. As the ++i/--j is done at least once for every run of the outer while loop, those values will eventually leave the valid range for accessing the array. And as those indices are used for accessing the array, you inescapable will get that segfault.